# Msg 16929, The cursor is READ ONLY - why?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures, triggers

We're building app that we designed around a database schema where we used `IDENTITY` columns as primary key. It's been decided that the customers need a more "user-friendly" identifier - a date string of the form `YYYYDDDNNNN`, where `YYYY` is the year, `DDD` the day of the year, and `NNNN` the sequence within the day, starting at 1.

Rather than reworking every child table to use this new complex key, we've decided to retain the current `IDENTITY` as primary key of the parent table, and for the foreign key relationships with the child tables, we've simply added a new identifier column to the parent table. The thing is - we'd like to populate this field automatically, on inserting new rows.

One modest complication - we have multiple customers, who will have overlapping sequences. On January 1st, each will have a record with identifier `20140010001`.

So, we've created a sequence table that contains `CustomerId`, `LastUpdateDate`, `LastSequenceNumber`.

And a stored procedure that is passed a `CustomerId` and returns a formatted identifier, updating the sequence table to keep track of what has already been used (this need to update the sequence table is why it is not a function)

Finally, we have an `AFTER INSERT` trigger on the parent record:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_incidentnumber] 
   ON  [dbo].[IMincident] 
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT customerid, incidentid 
            FROM inserted
        FOR UPDATE OF incidentnumber

    DECLARE @customerid NVARCHAR(32)
    DECLARE @incidentid int
    DECLARE @incidentnumber NVARCHAR(12)

    OPEN cur

    FETCH NEXT FROM cur 
        INTO @customerid, @incidentid

    WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
    BEGIN

        EXECUTE sp_getIMID @customerid, @incidentnumber OUTPUT

        UPDATE IMincident
            SET incidentnumber = @incidentnumber
            WHERE CURRENT OF cur

        FETCH NEXT FROM cur
            INTO @customerid, @incidentid
    END

    CLOSE cur
    DEALLOCATE cur
END
```

That seems pretty straightforward, for a trigger that needs a cursor (we need a cursor because we're calling a stored procedure for each row, and it has to be a stored procedure because functions can't update the database)

But, it doesn't work. I get an error:

> Msg 16929, Level 16, State 1, Procedure tr_incidentnumber, Line 34
>   The cursor is READ ONLY.
>   The statement has been terminated.

And I don't understand why. The best explanation I can find on the web for this error is here: http://support.microsoft.com/KB/158773

From it, I understand that my cursor would be READ ONLY, if the underlying table did not have a primary key or unique index. But my table does have a primary key. I've even dropped the primary key (and the half-dozen foreign keys that depended on it), and then recreated it, and I still get the error.

The table itself is simple:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[IMincident](
    [customerid] [nvarchar](32) NOT NULL,
    [incidentid] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [createdbyoperatorid] [nvarchar](32) NOT NULL,
    [createddt] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [currentrevisionnumber] [int] NOT NULL,
    [incidentnumber] [nvarchar](32) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_IMincident] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [incidentid] ASC
)
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

So, any ideas why I should be getting a 16929 error?

Comment: I don't think references to `inserted` in an *after insert* trigger are updatable.  You probably want a *before insert* or *instead of insert* trigger.  As the documentation says:  "You cannot directly modify the data in the tables" (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx).

Comment: Which **version** of SQL Server are you on? It might be a lot easier, if you're using SQL Server **2012** or newer, to use a `SEQUENCE` object which can dish out consecutive numbers - and thus you could get rid of the extremely ugly *cursor-in-a-trigger* setup! That sequence could be reset every night at midnight back to `1`.

Comment: Which version?  Depends on the customer.  We need to work with 2005, 2008, and 2012. And if we were using 2012, we'd need a distinct sequence for every customer.

Comment: Since you already have the primary key of the table in a variable could you not just change `WHERE CURRENT OF cur` to `WHERE incidentid = @incidentid`?

Comment: Oddly enough, the above trigger works just fine, if I do a normal update, using "WHERE incidentid = @incidentid" instead of using "WHERE  CURRENT OF cur".

Comment: That's because you are not trying to update the cursor, you are updating the table. The cursor references the read only `inserted` table, so the update fails. Although even if you could modify it you would still get an error (*The cursor does not include the table being modified or the table is not updatable through the cursor.*) since you are trying to update a table not referenced in the cursor, ([Example of error on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/156b6/2))

Comment: There is no circumstance where you should use a cursor in a trigger! What if a million records got updated? Cursors shoudl not be used by anyone except an experience DBA.  You need a set based process removing the use of the stored proc that make this be run one record at a time.

Comment: First, this is an insert trigger. It doesn't matter how many millions of records might be updated, it's not called.

Comment: Additionally, the business requirement is that every record have its incident number set according to these rules. If it's not done in a trigger, it will have to be done in code, which is going to be a higher load on the system than the trigger.

Comment: Finally, if you're aware of a set-based process for updating two tables in the same SQL statement, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: @HLGEM is right, there are better ways to have a unique reference number per customer without using a trigger. [Here is a very quick implementation](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/098510/1) that ensures reference numbers are unique per customer, by incrementing the previous reference by one with each insert.

Answer (score 0):

I'd find a better way of doing this than a Cursor, as they tend to be slow.  Plus the inserted and deleted tables you have in the trigger are virtual, maybe you could extrapolate the SP call into a select that's joined to inserted and/or deleted and perform all updates at once.  Depending on the changeset size you could easliy create timeout/locking issues